# Can't get expect result when migrating AffirmativeBased to AuthorizationManager

Tags: spring, spring-security

Recently I am working on migrating myself voter (AccessDecisionVoter) to AuthorizationManager in my project. I followed the [migrations document(5.8.3)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html) to implements AuthorizationManager but never successes.

My configuration like this way in spring-security-configure.xml

```
<security:filter-security-metadata-source id="metadataSource" use-expressions="true">
<security:intercept-url pattern="/xxxxx/xxxxx" method="DELETE" access="denyAll" 
...
...
</security:filter-security-metadata-source>
```

My authorizationManager sample code like this:

```
public class DenyAllAuthorizationManager implements AuthorizationManager<Object>
{
    private final static String DENY_ALL = "denyAll";
    private SecurityMetadataSource securityMetadataSource;

    @Override
    public AuthorizationDecision check(Supplier<Authentication> authentication, Object object)
    {
        //final var requestWrapper = (SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper) object;
        //final var request = (HttpServletRequest)requestWrapper.getRequest();
        final var attribute = getSecurityMetadataSource().getAttributes(object);

        if (isDeny(attribute))
        {
            return new AuthorizationDecision(false);
        }

        return new AuthorizationDecision(true);
    }


    private boolean isDeny(final ConfigAttribute cfg)
    {
        return cfg.getAttribute().equals(DENY_ALL);
    }

    public void setSecurityMetadataSource(final SecurityMetadataSource securityMetadataSource)
    {
        this.securityMetadataSource = securityMetadataSource;
    }
```

Based on document, this T (AuthorizationManager < T >) can be Object, MethodInvocation or RequestAuthorizationContext, but from my debug, it only is SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper type, which caused getSecurityMetadataSource().getAttributes(object) throwing cast exception.

Exception like this:

```
class org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.web.FilterInvocation
```

Many thanks for help.